# How to configure and run nginx-gridfs

Tags: c, mongodb, github, nginx

I am trying to run nginx-gridfs from github to connect mongodb with nginx . I followed the exact procedure as shown in the https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs README file .

I compiled and make nginx in my system.by following step

```
$ ./configure --add-module=/path/to/nginx-gridfs/source/
$ make
$ make install
```

Now what to do next

I am unable to understand how to impliment Configuration Directives part in in README file .

Now the nginx-gridfs has ngx_http_gridfs_module.c .Do I have to compile it and run it in order to see the response .I compiled and make mongo c drivers and run the example.c it ran well .

Do somebody guide me or give me some good links which explains step by step configuration of nginx-gridfs .

My final aim is to link nginx+mongodb+C code ..

please help me ...